# serverSideProps returning undefined

Tags: next.js

I'm using server side props in NextJS. I'm exporting the **`getServerSideProps`** from *`pages/Courses.js`*. My issue is that I'm receiving the props undefined in Courses function.

Courses.js:

```
function Courses({ props }) {
  console.log(props); 
  ....
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(process.env.url);
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {data}
  }
}
export default Courses
```

The data is not undefined, I can see the data coming from the server in the network tab. The props in console gives me undefined. Did I miss something here?

Comment: You are passing a prop named `data` from `getServerSideProps`, so you should access  it in `Courses` as such: `function Courses({ data }) { console.log(data);  ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is destructuring the argument and searching for `props` field. There is nothing like that there. Try something like this:

```
function Courses({ data }) {
  console.log(data); 
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch(process.env.url);
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {data}
  }
}
export default Courses
```

Everything what was passed to `props` field server side will be passed as a arguments to `Courses` function.

Comment: It throws ReferenceError: props is not defined

Comment: I checked it out here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#using-getserversideprops-to-fetch-data-at-request-time

Try this:

function Courses(props) {
  console.log(props); 
}

without destructuring the object, then check what's inside props.